# C: Passing files as parameters

Tags: c, io

I am having trouble passing a FILE pointer as a parameter into multiple functions.

I want to open the file in main, then pass it down into a function, which will write some things into it, then from that function pass it into another function. I can pass it from main to the first function no problem, but when I try to pass it to the second function it has a Segmentation fault.

My code looks something like this:

```
void firstFunction(FILE*);
void secondFunction(FILE*);

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  if((fp = fopen("test.txt", "ab+")) == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  firstFunction(fp);
  return 0;
}

void firstFunction(FILE *fp) {
  fprintf(fp, "test");  /* Works */
  secondFunction(fp);   /* Causes Segmentation fault */
}

void secondFunction(FILE *fp) {
  /* never reaches here */
  fprintf(fp, "test2");
}
```

This pretty well explains where I'm at with this. I've tried passing in various different syntaxes, such as secondFunction(*fp), but with no success.

Whats going wrong? How come it works when going from main to firstFunction but not from first to secondFunction?

EDIT: Actual Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINESIZE 512

void runCommand(const char[], FILE*);
    void append(const char[], FILE*);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char filename[LINESIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    char line[LINESIZE];

    sscanf(argv[1], "%s", filename);

    /* Open file for saving data */
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "ab+")) == 0) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    } else {    
        /* Reads lines from user */
        while(fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin)){
            /* Omits empty lines */
            if(strlen(line) > 1) {
                runCommand(line, fp);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Parses first word in input and executes proper command */
void runCommand(const char input[], FILE *fp) {
    char param1[LINESIZE];

    fprintf(fp, "test");
    append(input, fp);

    int r = sscanf(input, "%s", param1);

    if (!strcmp(param1, "append")){
        append(input, fp);
    } else {
        /* Error Handling */
    }   
}

void append(const char input[], FILE *fp) {
    char command[7];
    char fName[20];
    char lName[20];
    int score;

    int r = sscanf(input, "%s%s%s%d", command, fName, lName, score);

    if (r != 4) {
        /* Error Handling */
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%s%s%d", fName, lName, score);
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? It won't compile without a semicolon after `FILE *fp` on line 5 and `#include <stdio.h>` at the beginning. But with those alterations, it compiles and runs just fine on my system.

Comment: Please provide the real code that can repro the seg fault. The above code will not have that result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @kaylum I deleted my post, however, imho it actually answers the question very well, because by showing (and actually proving) that his code actually works, I show him, that his missing parts were the problem which should really help him.

Comment: Without `#include <stdio.h>`, `fopen()` has no declaration.  The implicit declaration will be expected to return `int`.  Which you then try to stuff into a `FILE *` pointer.  If you're compiling on a 64-bit Linux system with GCC, the default is to compile a 64-bit binary.  On a 64-bit Linux binary, an `int` is 32 bits, while a pointer is 64 bits.  Hence you get a `SIGSEGV` when you try to actually use your likely-to-be-truncated-to-32-bits `FILE *` pointer.  Lesson: pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: without #include <stdio.h>, compilation stops at "FILE *fp;"   /edit: no, actually it stops at void firstFunction(FILE*); already

Comment: Just as @squeamishossifrage [great username, btw] did, I cut and pasted the source code exactly as you posted it, added `#include <stdio.h>`, added a missing semicolon, and it compiled and worked perfectly.  Did your actual code have `#include <stdio.h>`?  Did you get any compilation warnings?

Comment: I did have `#include <stdio.h>` I just didn't add it in my snippet. Stripped down actual code added in edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ gcc -g -W -Wall -Wextra x.c -o x
x.c: In function 'append':
x.c:56:5: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 6 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
     int r = sscanf(input, "%s%s%s%d", command, fName, lName, score);
     ^
x.c:56:9: warning: 'score' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     int r = sscanf(input, "%s%s%s%d", command, fName, lName, score);
         ^
$ valgrind ./x test.txt 
==16814== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16814== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16814== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16814== Command: ./x test.txt
==16814== 
a b c 123
==16814== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==16814==    at 0x4E9B2D9: _IO_vfscanf (in /lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==16814==    by 0x4EA9BAB: __isoc99_vsscanf (in /lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==16814==    by 0x4EA9B26: __isoc99_sscanf (in /lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==16814==    by 0x400A4A: append (x.c:56)
==16814==    by 0x400993: runCommand (x.c:39)
==16814==    by 0x4008F9: main (x.c:26)
```

You're passing score in line 56 in your call to sscanf, but you should pass it's address. So add an ampersand:

```
int r = sscanf(input, "%s%s%s%d", command, fName, lName, &score);
```

After that, the error is gone and test.txt reads like this:

```
testbc123testcd23cd23
```

In C, arguments to functions are ALWAYS call by value. So if sscanf should write to the variable, passing the variable doesn't help. You actually have to pass it's address, so sscanf can write to it. That the other three variables (command, fName and lName) don't need an ampersand is because in C, you also cannot pass arrays. If you try to pass an array, indeed you're passing a pointer to it's first element. So the function prototypes

```
void runCommand(const char[], FILE*);
    void append(const char[], FILE*);
```

are actually missleading, because what they really mean is this:

```
void runCommand(const char *, FILE*);
    void append(const char *, FILE*);
```

and in your call to sscanf, the arrays "fall down" to pointers (so sscanf can actually write into their contents).

/edit: Slightly modified code to include some newlines in the fprintf statements (and a note where the call was) and this is the output of above's inputs:

```
runCommand: test
append: bc123
runCommand: test
append: cd23
append: cd23
```

Comment: Will likely solve a minor error in the future, but at this point does not solve the problem listed above.

Comment: Yes, it does. Just a sec, going to add output of cat test.txt - done (hmm there was still content in that file from previous runs ... but you see the bc123 - it that output is not what you expect, you got a different problem).

Comment: did you actually try my change in the sscanf statement?

Comment: You're correct! I'm sorry, when I first tried your solution I wasn't paying attention and added the ampersand on the wrong line. I was so obsessed with the FILE pointer being the cause of the segmentation fault (as I had been struggling with it before) that I was blind to it possible coming from a different pointer... Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome ;) - and take a look at the tool I used that actually pointed out the error immediately. That tool it your friend ;)